# How to create and run a make file for C?

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 files

```
hellomain.c
hellofunc.c
helloheader.h
```

and I am running via the GCC compiler. Usually I would type in:

```
gcc helloheader.h hellomain.c hellofunc.c -o results
```

And everything would run.

How could this be converted to a makefile? I know I have to title it `makefile`. I know I have to call it by typing in `make` in the compiler. But not sure what to actually type in the makefile.

Comment: There are thousands of examples and tutorials of makefiles. Start by copy one of the simpler and work from there.

Comment: Also, you should not really build the header file.

Comment: I tried following the examples in here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-2.3 But could not get it to work.

Comment: While the example you follow is well-commented, it's not really *simple* (IMO). I'll be nice and write up a very simple makefile. Hold on.

Comment: If all you need is to shorten your command, just make an [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) or a [script](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html). Or, of you're using Windows, a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file). You need a makefile only when you want to minimize your compilation time, and if you have just 2 source files, any optimization of this sort cannot be significant.

Comment: yeah i understand just want to test it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just about the simplest makefile possible for a project like your would be something like this:

```
# The name of the source files
SOURCES = hellomain.c hellofunc.c

# The name of the executable
EXE = results

# Flags for compilation (adding warnings are always good)
CFLAGS = -Wall

# Flags for linking (none for the moment)
LDFLAGS =

# Libraries to link with (none for the moment)
LIBS =

# Use the GCC frontend program when linking
LD = gcc

# This creates a list of object files from the source files
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

# The first target, this will be the default target if none is specified
# This target tells "make" to make the "all" target
default: all

# Having an "all" target is customary, so one could write "make all"
# It depends on the executable program
all: $(EXE)

# This will link the executable from the object files
$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o  $(EXE) $(LIBS)

# This is a target that will compiler all needed source files into object files
# We don't need to specify a command or any rules, "make" will handle it automatically
%.o: %.c

# Target to clean up after us
clean:
    -rm -f $(EXE)      # Remove the executable file
    -rm -f $(OBJECTS)  # Remove the object files

# Finally we need to tell "make" what source and header file each object file depends on
hellomain.o: hellomain.c helloheader.h
hellofunc.o: hellofunc.c helloheader.h
```

It *could* be even simpler, but with this you have some flexibility.

---

Just for completeness sake, this is probably the most simple makefile possible:

```
results: hellomain.c hellofunc.c helloheader.h
    $(CC) hellomain.c hellofunc.c -o results
```

This is basically doing what you're already doing on the command-line. It's not very flexible and it will rebuild everything if any file changes.

Comment: So pasted the most basic version you've posted here to test it out into a makefile without any extension. But when I type make and press enter I get *** missing separator. Stop.

Comment: @DanielD It's imperative that the spaces before the commands are *tabs*. It can't be e.g. four spaces. You have to edit the file to make sure they are tabs.

Comment: ah right forgot about that remember reading that too! thank you it worked now i can build upon this :)

Comment: The "most simple Makefile possible" can be simplified further by removing the second line. The builtin rules will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `makefile` with hard-coded file names. It's easy to follow, but may be tedious to update when you add/remove source and header files.

```
results: hellomain.o hellofunc.o
    gcc $^ -o results

hellomain.o: hellomain.c helloheader.h
    gcc -c $<

hellofunc.o: hellofunc.c helloheader.h
    gcc -c $<
```

Make sure to use the tab character for indentations in the makefile.